# How can I avoid dicttoxml producing underscore in keys

Tags: python, dicttoxml

I am using dicttoxml to write a dictionary structure to an xml file.

For example

```
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
myDict= {"This is a key": "some value"}
myRecord= dicttoxml(myDict, attr_type=False, root=False)
```

When checking the output file 'This is a key' and the value got converted into

`<This_is_a_key>some value</This_is_a_key>`

Is there a way to avoid the conversion to underscore so instead I get

`<This is a key>some value</This is a key>`

Comment: Why? If it did that, it wouldn't be valid xml.

Comment: This would produce invalid XML. Why?

Comment: with this attempt `<This is a key>` - any of `is`, `a` or `key` could be perceived as attributes. This is incorrect and should not be viable

Comment: Agreed - in this case I just need to output it this way because of another system requiring column headers that maintain the original key.  Not ideal I know. I probably will look into avoiding the xml route completely and instead write into a csv file directly.  Thanks for the comments!